# Reference class variable in a comprehension of another class variable

Tags: python, dictionary, class-variables

This may be a simple question, but I'm having trouble making a unique search for it.

I have a class that defines a static dictionary, then attempts to define a subset of that dictionary, also statically.

So, as a toy example:

```
class example(object): 
    first_d = {1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4} 
    second_d = dict((k,first_d[k]) for k in (2,3))
```

This produces  `NameError: global name 'first_d' is not defined`

How should I be making this reference? It seems this pattern works in other cases, eg:

```
class example2(object):
    first = 1
    second = first + 1
```

Comment: that's not a "static" dictionary.

Comment: And why can't those be instance variables?

Comment: Hmmm oddly enough, this works fine: `second_d = {k: v for k, v in first_d.items() if k in (2, 3)}`

Comment: @ColinDunklau: I'm trying to imitate an enum, I guess. I'm writing a controller for a 3rd party program, for which I'll assemble a text file of control parameters. These are modular, and largely fixed. My controller should only run a subset of these each time. So I wanted each controller to have an instance variable defined as a subset of a dictionary defining all possible sets. The `second_d`, here, is the default set as opposed to the definitive set.  If this isn't the best way to do things, I'm happy to consider something else.

Comment: @JoelCornett I'm going with the solution in your comment unless there's a compelling reason not to. Could you put it as an answer so I can accept it, please?

Comment: Maybe I'll post it as an answer, but to be honest, I'm not too satisfied with it :p I'm genuinely curious to know _why_ mine works while your version doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic list comprehension has the following [syntax](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-sets-and-dictionaries)

```
[expression for var in iterable]
```

When a list comprehension occurs inside a class, the attributes of the class 
can be used in `iterable`. This is true in Python2 and Python3.

However, the attributes of the class can be used (i.e. accessed) in `expression` in Python2 but not in Python3.

The story is a bit different for generator expressions:

```
(expression for var in iterable)
```

While the class attributes can still be accessed from `iterable`, the class attributes are not accessible from `expression`. (This is true for Python2 and Python3).

This can all be summarized as follows:

```
                             Python2      Python3
Can access class attributes
--------------------------------------------------
list comp. iterable                Y            Y
list comp. expression              Y            N
gen expr. iterable                 Y            Y
gen expr. expression               N            N
dict comp. iterable                Y            Y
dict comp. expression              N            N
```

(Dict comprehensions behave the same as generator expressions in this respect.)

---

**Now how does this relate to your question:**

In your example,

```
second_d = dict((k,first_d[k]) for k in (2,3))
```

a `NameError` occurs because `first_d` is not accessible from the `expression` part of a generator expression.

A workaround for Python2 would be to change the generator expression to a list comprehension:

```
second_d = dict([(k,first_d[k]) for k in (2,3)])
```

However, I don't find this a very comfortable solution since this code will fail in Python3.

You could do as Joel Cornett suggests:

```
second_d = {k: v for k, v in first_d.items() if k in (2, 3)}
```

since this uses `first_d` in the `iterable` rather than the `expression` part of the dict comprehension. But this may loop through many more items than necessary if `first_d` contains many items. Neverthess, this solution might be just fine if `first_d` is small.

In general, you can avoid this problem by defining a helper function which can be defined inside or outside the class:

```
def partial_dict(dct, keys):
    return {k:dct[k] for k in keys}

class Example(object):
    first_d = {1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4}
    second_d = partial_dict(first_d, (2,3))

class Example2(object):
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    b = [2,4]
    def myfunc(A, B):
        return [x for x in A if x not in B]
    c = myfunc(a, b)

print(Example().second_d)
# {2: 2, 3: 3}

print(Example2().c)
# [1, 3, 5]
```

Functions work because they define a local scope and 
variables in this local scope can be accessed from within the dict comprehension.

This was [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11670273/190597), but I am not entirely comfortable with this since it does not explain why the `expression` part behaves differently than the `iterable` part of a list comprehension, generator expression or dict comprehension.

Thus I can not explain (completely) *why* Python behaves this way, only that this is the way it appears to behave.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer unutbu. For people trying to use a list comprehension / iterable to initialize a static variable (in python 3), this is a potential solution: define the comprehension/iterable as a function as mentioned above (and tag it with `@staticmethod`) e.g. `myfunc(params)`, then call it using `myfunc.__func__(params)`. Actually, I'll just edit the answer to include an example.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit kludgy, but you could try this:

```
class test(object):
    pass

test.first = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4}
test.second = dict((k, test.first[k]) for k in (2,3))
```

...and then:

```
>>> test.first
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
>>> test.second
{2: 2, 3: 3}

>>> t = test()
>>> t.first
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
>>> t.second
{2: 2, 3: 3}

>>> test.first[5] = 5
>>> t.first
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}
```

Comment: Any idea _why_ it doesn't work, given that this does work: `second_d = {k: v for k, v in first_d.items() if k in (2, 3)}`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the class exists until you get to the end of its definition.